# Client and server side validation using RESTfull and AngularJs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, rest

What is the best way to implement validation between RESTfull service (c#) and AngularJs?

I have RESTfull service that will return ViewModel that will be used by AngularJs. I would like to implement something like C# MVC validation i.e. to define on server side validation on the model and angular can add on the inputs fields.

```
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
      [CustomValidation]
      [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2)]
      public string Title { get; set; }

 <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
 </div>
```